# Как скопировать файл в системную папку

Tags: android

Пишу приложение, которое должно копировать и заменять файл в /data, естественно на рутованном устройстве, как это сделать?

Comment: Приложение может попасть в системную папку, только если подписать его системным сертификатом (лавочка прикрыта). А вот с помощью команды su можно делать то, что Вы хотите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process suProcess;

suProcess = r.exec("su");

DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
dos.writeBytes("rm " + абсолютный_путь_к_файлу_который_надо_заменить + "\n");
dos.flush();
dos.writeBytes("cat " абсолютный_путь_копируемого_файла + ">> " + путь_назначения);
dos.flush();
```